# How can I set up this Python file to set d = dict() with the correct data so I can use it in all methods? This python file is called through C++

Tags: python, c++

Python File:

```
import re
import string

class Dictonary:

    d = dict()

    def __init__(self):
       Dictonary.d = storeData();

def storeData():
    text = open("CS210_Project_Three_Input_File.txt", "r")
    d = dict()
    for line in text:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.lower()
        words = line.split(" ")
        for word in words:
            if word in d:
                d[word] = d[word] + 1
            else:
                d[word] = 1
    return d;


def countTimesEveryItemOccurs():
    for key in list(Dictonary.d.keys()):
        print(key, ":", Dictonary.d[key])
```

I call this Python file within the C++ file below. I want to be able to set the quantity of all the items in the text file when I first call the menu. Since each option will need that data, I would not like to recall the same code over and over. I would like to set the data within d = dict(). What would be the best way to set this up? Maybe set up a Class within Python file?

C++ File:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

/*
Description:
    To call this function, simply pass the function name in Python that you wish to call.
Example:
    callProcedure("printsomething");
Output:
    Python will print on the screen: Hello from python!
Return:
    None
*/
void CallProcedure(string pName)
{
    char* procname = new char[pName.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(procname, pName.c_str());

    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject* my_module = PyImport_ImportModule("PythonCode");
    PyErr_Print();
    PyObject* my_function = PyObject_GetAttrString(my_module, procname);
    PyObject* my_result = PyObject_CallObject(my_function, NULL);
    Py_Finalize();

    delete[] procname;
}

/*
Description:
    To call this function, pass the name of the Python functino you wish to call and the string parameter you want to send
Example:
    int x = callIntFunc("PrintMe","Test");
Output:
    Python will print on the screen:
        You sent me: Test
Return:
    100 is returned to the C++
*/
int callIntFunc(string proc, string param)
{
    char* procname = new char[proc.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(procname, proc.c_str());

    char* paramval = new char[param.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(paramval, param.c_str());


    PyObject* pName, * pModule, * pDict, * pFunc, * pValue = nullptr, * presult = nullptr;
    // Initialize the Python Interpreter
    Py_Initialize();
    // Build the name object
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"PythonCode");
    // Load the module object
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    // pDict is a borrowed reference 
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
    // pFunc is also a borrowed reference 
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, procname);
    if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
    {
        pValue = Py_BuildValue("(z)", paramval);
        PyErr_Print();
        presult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pValue);
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    else
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    //printf("Result is %d\n", _PyLong_AsInt(presult));
    Py_DECREF(pValue);
    // Clean up
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    Py_DECREF(pName);
    // Finish the Python Interpreter
    Py_Finalize();

    // clean 
    delete[] procname;
    delete[] paramval;


    return _PyLong_AsInt(presult);
}

/*
Description:
    To call this function, pass the name of the Python functino you wish to call and the string parameter you want to send
Example:
    int x = callIntFunc("doublevalue",5);
Return:
    25 is returned to the C++
*/
int callIntFunc(string proc, int param)
{
    char* procname = new char[proc.length() + 1];
    std::strcpy(procname, proc.c_str());

    PyObject* pName, * pModule, * pDict, * pFunc, * pValue = nullptr, * presult = nullptr;
    // Initialize the Python Interpreter
    Py_Initialize();
    // Build the name object
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"PythonCode");
    // Load the module object
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    // pDict is a borrowed reference 
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
    // pFunc is also a borrowed reference 
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, procname);
    if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc))
    {
        pValue = Py_BuildValue("(i)", param);
        PyErr_Print();
        presult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pValue);
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    else
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }
    //printf("Result is %d\n", _PyLong_AsInt(presult));
    Py_DECREF(pValue);
    // Clean up
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    Py_DECREF(pName);
    // Finish the Python Interpreter
    Py_Finalize();

    // clean 
    delete[] procname;

    return _PyLong_AsInt(presult);
}

string nCharString(int t_length, char t_character) { //Parameter: length, (Number of times character is repeated) / Parameter character (Character to be repeated).
    string returnString;                         //String to be returned.
    for (int i = 0; i < t_length; i++) {             //Loop 'length' amount of times.  
        returnString += t_character;                 //Adding the 'character' to 'returnString' each time.
    }
    return returnString;                         //Return 'returnString'.
}

boolean checkIfDigitAndRange(string input, int lowEnd, int highEnd, int& choice) {
    if (isdigit(input[0])) {
        int temp = stoi(input);
        if (temp >= lowEnd && temp <= highEnd) {
            choice = temp;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            cout << "Out of range choice, try again!" << endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
    cout << "Digit was not entered, try again!" << endl;
    return false;   // If NOT digit
}

boolean checkIfInputYesOrNo(char input) {
    if (input == 'y' || input == 'Y')
        return true;
    return false;
}

void readFile() {   // Function to read the file with a paramater of a vector composed of City objects, and a & sign since we will change this vector's contents.
    fstream file;   // Create fstream instance.
    file.open("CS210_Project_Three_Input_File.txt", ios::in);    // Open the file. 
    if (file.is_open()) {   
        string line;   
        while (getline(file, line)) { 
 
        }
        cout << "CS210_Project_Three_Input_File.txt opened and read successfully!" << endl;  
    }
    else   // If file was not open. 
        cout << "Unable to open file\n";    // Print to console to show that it was NOT successful.
    file.close();   // Close file, this is so we can use the file again. 
}

void choiceOne() {
    cout << "List of quantity of each item purchased on a given day." << endl << nCharString(55, '-') << endl;
    CallProcedure("countTimesEveryItemOccurs");
    cout << endl << "Would you like to rerun this program? Enter 'Y' for yes, enter anything else for no!" << endl;
}

void choiceTwo() {
    string itemToFind;
    cout << "Enter an item to see how much that item sold on a given day:" << endl;
    cin >> itemToFind;
    system("cls");
    cout << itemToFind << " was sold " << callIntFunc("countSpecificItemOccurances", itemToFind) << "times!";
    
}

void choiceThree() {

}

int getMenuAndChoice() {
    char yOrNo;
    string input;
    while (true) {
        int choice = 0;
        cout << nCharString(78, '-') << endl;
        cout << "Choose an option, '1', '2', '3', or '4'" << endl;
        cout << "1: Produce list of number of times each item was purchased." << endl;
        cout << "2: Produce a number representing how many times a specific item was purchased." << endl;
        cout << "3: Produce a text-based histogram listing all items purchased." << endl;
        cout << "4: Exit Program." << endl;
        cout << nCharString(78, '-') << endl;
        cin >> input;
        system("cls");
        if (checkIfDigitAndRange(input, 1, 4, choice)) {
            if (choice == 1) {
                choiceOne();
                cin >> yOrNo;
                if (!checkIfInputYesOrNo(yOrNo))
                    break;
                system("cls");
            }
            else if (choice == 2) {
                choiceTwo();
                cin >> yOrNo;
                if (!checkIfInputYesOrNo(yOrNo))
                    break;
                system("cls");
            }
            else if (choice == 3) {
                choiceThree();
                cin >> yOrNo;
                if (!checkIfInputYesOrNo(yOrNo))
                    break;
                system("cls");
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}


void main()
{
    getMenuAndChoice();

}
```

Comment: There are several ways.  (1) You could return `d` after you create it and pass it to the future functions. (2) You could store `d` in a global in the Python code.  (3) You could turn this into a class, and store `d` in a member variable.  Option 3 is probably the best.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have tried to do the class and store d in a member variable, but the data will not store correctly. Would I call a function to store this data within my __init__ function? I will edit my post to show you what I have, the data is not storing. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Those functions would need to be MEMBER functions of `Dictionary`.  Your C++ code would then create a `Dictionary` objects, and call the member functions instead of calling global functions.

Comment: @TimRoberts Alright thank you I will mess with it.